# SQL Cross-Schema stored procedure permission issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a simplified stored procedure

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [FooSchema].[Foo]
AS
SELECT
    B.*,
    FROM [BarSchema].[Bar] AS B
    WHERE [...]
```

After granting EXEC to a user on the FooSchema, but not on the BarSchema, this stored procedure will fail with the message

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Bar',
```

Is there a way to make the user access [FooSchema].[Foo] without exposing [BarSchema].[Bar]'s entire data set as the stored procedure already filters out data relevant to this user.

Comment: MySQL has a `DEFINER = USERNAME` to a PROCEDURE which is checking access privileges at routine execution time, i was looking for the same in SQL Server (MSSQL) but it seams to be non existing..

Comment: If both schemas are owned by the same user, normal ownership chaining will apply and users with exec permissions on the proc don't need permissions on the underlying objects.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for that, but I was hoping I could keep both of those separated.

Comment: @RaymondNijland is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) what you meant?

Comment: If `[BarSchema].[Bar]` and `[FooSchema].[Foo]` do have the same owner, then the only other reason you would be getting that error is that there is an explicit `DENY` permission to the object `[BarSchema].[Bar]` to the user trying to use the SP `[FooSchema].[Foo]`.

Comment: Yes that is what i more or less meant. when i rechecked the [CREATE PROCEDURE BNF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) i looked SQL Server has `[ WITH EXECUTE AS Clause ]` which @Greg has written a answer about it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest option is to use `[WITH EXECUTE AS]` statement, where the username specified has the exact permissions needed for the objects in question.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [FooSchema].[Foo]
WITH EXECUTE AS '<username>'
AS
SELECT
    B.*,
    FROM [BarSchema].[Bar] AS B
    WHERE [...]
```

Answer (score 3):

If both schemas are owned by the same user, normal ownership chaining will apply and users with `EXECUTE` permissions on the proc don't need permissions on the underlying objects. Users will be restricted to the data returned by the stored procedure and won't be able to perform ad-hoc queries on the tables unless you specifically grant them permissions to do so.

For example:

```
CREATE USER SchemaOwner WITHOUT LOGIN;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::FooSchema TO SchemaOwner;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::BarSchema TO SchemaOwner;
```

Another method to provide additional permissions only within the scope of the module is with module signing.

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE FooUserCertificate
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '0bfuscatedPassword'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Allow access to bar table';

CREATE USER FooUser FROM CERTIFICATE FooUserCertificate;

GRANT SELECT ON BarSchema.Bar TO FooUser;

ADD SIGNATURE TO FooSchema.Foo BY CERTIFICATE FooUserCertificate
    WITH PASSWORD = '0bfuscatedPassword';

ALTER CERTIFICATE FooUserCertificate REMOVE PRIVATE KEY;
GO
```

Albeit more complex, the advantage of module signing over `EXECUTE AS` is that the original caller's identity is preserved during execution and not sandboxed in the current database. This is useful for auditing and cross-database access. See [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) for more information.